# How to test CSV upload across different browsers

Tags: cross-browser

I usually use a site like Browserstack or Browsershots for cross-browser testing. In this case though, the functionality I'm testing is the ability to upload CSV files. I'm not sure how to test this, since you can't upload CSVs on the remote servers via the services I listed above.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time when someone gripes about cross browser testing they are really griping about IE. I hate IE. However MS has recently made available VMs for testing old versions of IE:

**http://www.modern.ie/en-us**

Download the VM, run it in virtualbox, hit your localhost with the browser. Done.

---

When will Apple follow suite? Safari on mac is a different animal than Safari on windows, and passing around an old macbook for smoke testing is a pain.